# How can i see messages from DLQ on Jboss AS 7?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, hornetq

I'm using Jboss AS 7.1.1 and i need to see the messages that are in DLQ (Dead Letter Queue).

I tried writing a simple MDB for it:

```
@MessageDriven(messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class, activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/queue/DLQ"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1") })
public class DLQMDB implements MessageListener{
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        process(message);
    } ...
}
}
```

I wrote another MDB that throws error so the messages will do to the DLQ, but the DLQ MDB is never triggered.

I don't know if it is because there are no messages in the DLQ or the MDB is not defined correctly.

What am i doing wrong? Is there another way to see messages in the DLQ (like logging, admin interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work, I had a configuration problem:

```
<address-setting match="jms.queue.MetricEvents">
      <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.MyQueue</dead-letter-address>
      <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
      <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
      <max-delivery-attempts>0</max-delivery-attempts>
      <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
      <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
      <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
 </address-setting>
```

once i removed :

```
<max-delivery-attempts>0</max-delivery-attempts>
```

everything is working.